# Makefile dependencies with Sweave

Tags: makefile, sweave

I am trying to compile a Sweave document with a makefile, using data stored in another directory, assembled by a script in the current directory. The workflow goes something like this:

> datamaker.R > /otherdirectory/data > .rnw > .tex > .pdf

I currently have a makefile similar to the creation below:

```
MASTER = foo.pdf
VPATH = /otherdirectory
all: $(MASTER)
    open $<

data: datamaker.R
    R CMD BATCH 'datamaker.R'

foo.rnw: data

foo.tex: foo.rnw
    R CMD SWEAVE 'foo.rnw'

foo.pdf: foo.tex
    pdflatex foo.tex
```

The problem is that the R CMD BATCH command runs every time, even when 'datamaker' is older than 'data'. I'm sure that I'm missing something fairly obvious, but I've been pulling my hair out for several hours now.

Comment: A guess: the `R CMD BATCH` command actually produces `data` in `otherdirectory/`, not in the current directory, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Make is trying to use the `data` rule to build `data`, which is the prerequisite of `foo.rnw`, but the `data` rule doesn't actually build `data`, it builds `otherdirectory/data`. So Make runs it every time, because `data` is never there.

Try this:

```
...

otherdirectory/data: datamaker.R
    R CMD BATCH 'datamaker.R'

foo.rnw: otherdirectory/data

...
```

Comment: I thought this was the purpose of adding the VPATH variable. At any rate, calling the path specifically does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you check the timestamps and verify that 1) `otherdirectory/data` exists, 2) it's newer than `datamaker.R` and 3) the `otherdirectory/data` rule is still being executed? I want to be sure, because the next step is pretty involved.

Comment: The time stamps are valid, but i have found another way around the issue. I would be interested to hear the next step if you want to provide it, however.